# Link to open tab

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

Im sure a very schoolboy question.

I'm using the tabs example from here http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

[image]
And would be interested to know how to link from a external page to a specific open tab ie:Tokyo tab. It looks like there are ids on the tabs but don't seem to display them in the url bar.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the url of the page using JavaScript and show tab depending on the necessary hash

Comment: Thanks, would you mind advising on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

The external link can be simply added in the new `a href` parameter of the tab. The code would look something like this:

```
  <li><a href="#" class="tablinks"><a href="linkToTokyoCity">Tokyo</a></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, not sure my question was clear. I wish to add the link to a separate page to that tab

Comment: Please replace linkToTokyoCity with the external link

Comment: Im not trying to add a link in the tab content as your suggestion does, im trying to add a link to completely different page to open that tokyo tab.